# Iframe do not show in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I've an iframe that do not display in internet explorer 9 & 8, i can see it only in firefox and google chrome.
here is my doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Here is the iframe code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="325" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="https://maps.google.fr/maps/ms?t=m&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=207646320019934039639.0004dd3a4a62fad5cbba1&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=48.390202,-4.5086&amp;spn=0.010744,0.033023&amp;output=embed" width="325"></iframe>
```

I've tried this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

It did not help, how can i make it appear in internet explorer ?

Comment: Is the parent page also https?

Comment: tried on my computer your iframe and it looks like it works... maybe something else is interfering with it...

Comment: No the parent is not https